# React | Update State | using spread and array.push to update array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have jsfiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/ilikeflex/r2uws1ez/30/

I am trying to set new state by accessing the previous state. I have three different cases where i am trying to update the state but i am not sure why does Case2 and Case 3 does not work. Can you please help me ??

```
const useState = React.useState;

function Example() {
  
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([
    {id:1,text:'Learn React'},
    {id:2,text:'Learn TypeScript'},
    {id:3,text:'Learn Java'}
    ]);  
    
  const case1 = () => {
   const newItem = {id:3,text:'Learn C++'};
   
   setTodos((prevState) => {
    return prevState.concat(newItem);
   });
  
  }  
  
  const case2 = () => {
   const newItem = {id:3,text:'Learn .Net'};
   
   setTodos((prevState) => {
    prevState.push(newItem);  // I am adding to previous state and returning it
    return prevState;
   });
  
  }  
  
 const case3 = () => {
   const newItem = {id:3,text:'Learn C#'};
   
   setTodos((prevState) => {
    let result = { ...prevState, newItem }; // using spread operator
    return result;
   });
  
  }
  
  return (
    <div>

      <button onClick={case1}>Case 1</button>
      <button onClick={case2}>Case 2</button>
      <button onClick={case3}>Case 3</button>
      

      <ul>
            {todos.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>{item.text}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>    
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make case 2 work, you need to make a variable out of the prevState first. Then you can push to it and return that new variable.

```
const case2 = () => {
   const newItem = {id:3,text:'Learn .Net'};
   
   setTodos((prevState) => {
   const newState = [...prevState]
    newState.push(newItem);
    return newState;
   });
  
  }
```

For case 3, you made a little mistake by making result an object instead of an array. Change the `{}` to `[]` and it should work fine, like this.

```
const case3 = () => {
   const newItem = {id:3,text:'Learn C#'};
   
   setTodos((prevState) => {
    let result = [...prevState, newItem ] ;
    return result;
   });
  
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Aron for making Case 2 and Case 3 work. But in Case 2 why i need to create a new variable. In case 1 also i am not making new variable.

Comment: @Raj `.concat(value)` returns a new array with the value added to it. But `.push(value)` changes the existing array and does not return a new array.

Comment: @Aron Make sense. It is always new array need to be created

Answer (score -1):

In all the cases, a new array need be to created and returned.

Case 1.

```
return prevState.concat(newItem); [ concat create a new array ]
```

Case 2

```
const newState = [...prevState];  [ Spread Operator creates a new array ] 
    newState.push(newItem);
    return newState;
```

Case 3

```
 let result = [...prevState, newItem ] ; [ Spread Operator creates a new array and newItem is added simultaneously ]
    return result;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).